# Confusion regarding a method of writing constraint equations

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces

I came across a method for writing the constraint equations known as "The Virtual Work Method".I am quoting the exact language of the text(well,not exactly the exact)-

> Consider the atwood machine shown.When one holds both the masses such that the string is slack,there is no tension.Once released,the string will become taut and it will oppose the motion of one block where as it will support the motion of other one.
>
> [image: fig]
>
> Thus it is transferring the effort of one  block to the other one.so it will not do work on its own.Since sum of the work done by string on each block is 0
>
> $$\vec T\cdot\vec  x+\vec T\cdot\vec y=0 $$
> $$\Rightarrow \vec x+\vec y=0$$
> *Differentiating twice*
>
> $$\vec a_x+\vec a_y=0$$

Well here i do not not understand why sum of the work will be 0 and another thing is why is the work called virtual?

Comment: Have you read [Wikipedia's (quite exhaustive) take](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_work) on virtual work?

Comment: Since gravity is a conservative force the total energy of the system has to remain constant. The internal motion, will do no work overall since energy is constant.